# How to determine if my JavaScript is running in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script which has some program logic. I run this script using nodejs for real-time communication between server and clients. Sometime due to some errors nodejs stops and script fails to run. This is how I run my script

```
nodejs myscript.js
```

Now in this script if I have some error (lets say some undefined variable) Nodejs stops running and throws an error

```
ReferenceError: abcd is not defined
at WebSocket.open (/var/nodes/myserver/myscript.js:99:54)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:92:17)
```

Now how can I find out that my script stopped running because of some error?? I am sure that there is someway to achieve this. If this is not possible then I am ok to run another script (lets say watch.js) to have a track on myscript.js. But how to do this??

Thank You

Comment: `nodejs myscript.js ; echo "The End."`

Comment: [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) could be one tool to monitor it.

Answer (score 1):

A node process has an `uncaughtException` event which you can handle

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(`Caught exception: ${err}`);
});
```

See more details here https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

Comment: Bad practice. Your app in undefined state, you should terminate the process in callback anyway.

Comment: Right but before you terminate you can log to console or do some other cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Output stderr to log file and check it:

```
node myscript.js 2>>"log/`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T-%N"`.log"
```